# how to change background of unchecked checkbox in Tailwind 3 if ussing accent-color

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

i have checkbox input with class="accent-gray-500"

how can i change background color of "unchecked" state?
Tried to add ie "bg-red-500" to input class, but no luck.

(Tailwind 3.0.24)

tnx

[image]

Comment: you can't ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Property_compatibility_table_for_form_controls#check_boxes_and_radio_buttons) ) , you need to make custom one and use `<label>` tag to wrap it.